# How to pass argument to controller action with FluidTypo3?

Tags: typo3, flux, typo3-6.2.x

How do I have to pass an argument to a flux-enabled controller so it is recognized by the controller action?

I created an extension using builder and added the following method to the ContentController.

```
/**
 * @param string $var
 */
public function exampleAction($var = null) {
    var_dump($var);
    die;
}
```

But no matter how I add the parameter to the URL, I only get "null" as a result.

Extensions directory is "test" and so is `$_EXTKEY`. The builder put "Mac.Test" into `ext_tables.php` for calls to registerProviderExtensionKey(). So in the URL I tried these parameters:

```
http://host/index.php?id=1&tx_test_content[var]=abc
http://host/index.php?id=1&tx_test[var]=abc
http://host/index.php?id=1&tx_mactest_content[var]=abc
http://host/index.php?id=1&tx_mactest[var]=abc
http://host/index.php?id=1&var=abc
```

and some others. But to no avail.

I tried with the `f:link.action` ViewHelper, resulting in
`http://localhost/test2/index.php?id=1&no_cache=1&tx_test_content[member]=foo&tx_test_content[action]=example&tx_test_content[controller]=Content`

Also $this->request->getArguments() only returns an empty array, so there must be something seriously wrong.

Used versions:
PHP 5.6.11
TYPO3 6.2.21
vhs 2.4.0
flux 7.2.3
fluidpages 3.3.1
fluidcontent 4.3.3
fluidcontent_core 1.3.0
builder 1.0.0
Nothing else installed (fresh system just for testing this behaviour).

Comment: Is this a cachable controller action? If it is then it might not care about any arguments based on previous executions.

Comment: Can you post the calls to `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin()` in `ext_localconf.php` and `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin()` in `ext_tables.php`? The pluginname matters for the parameter name.

Comment: No, unfortunately I can't, as I'm using FluidTYPO3 (also known as flux). Thus there is no plugin configuration in ext_tables.php / ext_localconf.php. Or should I have it in this case? I didn't see any mention of it on the web anywhere.

Comment: @Jost: I gave it a try and added the plugin configuration with extension names "Test", "MacTest" and even "Mac.Test". No difference at all. Yes, I cleared the cache ;)

Comment: Not an answer, just a tip:
use `TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($var);` to debug. gives you some nice styled output

Answer (score 5):

Using fluid link, you can pass para like

```
<f:link.action action="example" controller="controllerName"  arguments="{var:'abc'}">Go</f:link.action>
```

It'll create link like:

```
http://host/index.php?id=1&tx_[extension_key]_[fe_plugin_key][var]=abc
```

Now, how to get para from url in extBase

```
$arguments = $this->request->getArguments(); // OR
$var = $this->request->getArgument('var');
```

Useful links:

- [Fluid](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/fluid/master.html)
- [extBase Accessing GET/POST vars](https://wiki.typo3.org/Extbase_HowTos)

Comment: Thanks for this try, but unfortunately it doesn't change anything. In fact I at first tried to generate the link via `f:link.action` ViewHelper and as that had no impact at all, I tried with other URL parameters. I should have noted that, though. `$this->request->getArguments()` returns an empty array. And even if it returned the value, I would lose lots of magic (like resolving a parameter to a fully loaded model). So unfortunately your tips don't help :(